# Android Studio doesn't start with JAVA_HOME variable setted

Tags: android, android-studio

I've a problem with Android Studio.
When i try to open Android Studio it shows this message:

[image]

But I've setted the JAVA_HOME variables (Java SKD is installed):

[image]

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by installing *Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package.*

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the 64bit JDK? You can install the 64bit JDK as follows:

**Windows**

> - Launch the downloaded EXE file, android-studio-bundle-.exe
> - Follow the setup wizard to install Android Studio.

**Known issue**

On some Windows systems, the launcher script does not find where Java is installed. If you encounter this problem, you need to set an environment variable indicating the correct location.

> - Select Start menu > Computer > System Properties > Advanced System Properties.
> - Open Advanced tab > Environment Variables
> - Add a new system variable JAVA_HOME that points to your JDK folder, for
>     example C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21.

Comment: Yes, I've installed the SDK for Win-64.